# Detecting STX and ETX in DataInputStream

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from a socket connection and trying to figure out how to get the data between the STX and ETX characters/int.

The structure of the response is STX SEQ DATA ETX LRC. I need to read everything between the STX and ETX and disregard the checksum(LRC).

So far I've got this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        int c;
        int prevC = 0;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            if(c == 3){
                break;
            }else if(c == 6){
                sb.append(MathOperations.convertIntToHex(c));
                break;
            }
            else{
                sb.append(MathOperations.convertIntToHex(c));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error reading loop socket ({})", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    String response = sb.toString();
    LOGGER.info("Received response from remote server - data ({})",response);
    return response;
```

The problem I currently have is that the LRC data is attached to the string as well. How can i get rid of it? is there a more elegant way of reading only the data in between?

The c == 6 is for checking acknowledgement of the request received from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I currently have is that the LRC data is attached to the string as well. How can i get rid of it?

The simple answer is to read the bytes of the LRC and throw them away.

> is there a more elegant way of reading only the data in between?

The [`skipBytes(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#skipBytes-int-) method will do the same thing.  Slightly more elegant ...